# force a file to 'save as' browser window

Tags: php, mysql

with the help of this function given below i want to save the dump of my database table on notepad but it don't let me save it but always display the data on browser what should i do to save it??? below the function i also post the function calling code. check it also

thanks a lot in advance

```
//function for making .sql file (dump)

    public function backup_tables($host,$user,$pass,$name,$tables = '*')

{

     $link = mysql_connect($host,$user,$pass);

     mysql_select_db($name,$link);

    //get all of the tables

    if($tables == '*')
    {
        $tables = array();

        $result = mysql_query('SHOW TABLES');

        print_r( $result);

        //die('result');

        while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))

        {
            $tables[] = $row[0];
        }

    }

    else

    {
        $tables = is_array($tables) ? $tables : explode(',',$tables);
    }

    //cycle through

    foreach($tables as $table)

    {

        $result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM '.$table);

        $num_fields = mysql_num_fields($result);

        //$return.= 'DROP TABLE '.$table.';';

        $row2 = mysql_fetch_row(mysql_query('SHOW CREATE TABLE '.$table));

        $return.= /*"\n\n".*/$row2[1].";\n\n";

        for ($i = 0; $i < $num_fields; $i++) 
        {
            while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
            {
                $return.= 'INSERT INTO '.$table.' VALUES(';

                for($j=0; $j<$num_fields; $j++) 

                {
                    $row[$j] = addslashes($row[$j]);

                    $row[$j] = ereg_replace("\n","\\n",$row[$j]);

                    if (isset($row[$j])) { $return.= '"'.$row[$j].'"' ; } else { $return.= '""'; }
                    if ($j<($num_fields-1)) { $return.= ','; }

                }
                $return.= ");\n";

            }
        }

        $return.="\n\n\n";

    }

    //save file

    $handle = fopen('./db_files/db-backup-'.date('d-m-Y_H-i-s').'-'.(implode(',',$tables)).'.sql','w+');

    header("Content-type:application/sql");

    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$filename.'" ');

    fwrite($handle,$return);

    fclose($handle);

}   
    // end of function for making .sql file (dump)


//call to a function

$this->backup_tables('host','user','pass','db name','table name');
```

Comment: Set content-type to `Content-Type:application/force-download` and it will call 'save as' dialog. Btw, you do not output the sql code, just saving it `fwrite($handle,$return);`  if you want to ouput, add `echo $return;`

Comment: `application/force-download` is *not* a valid MIME type and should not be used under any circumstances.

Answer (score 5):

[PHP Docs `header`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php): If you want the user to be prompted to save the data you are sending, such as a generated PDF file, you can use the » Content-Disposition header to supply a recommended filename and force the browser to display the save dialog.

```
<?php
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate");
header("Pragma: must-revalidate");

header("Content-type: text/csv");
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=$filename.csv");
// Your code here
?>
```

Comment: this the calling of a function but it don't give the proper sq. format. infact i am new to php that why i am too much confused. what should i do to make every thing absolutely ok

$this->backup_tables('host','user','password','database_name','table name');
        header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate");
        header("Pragma: must-revalidate");
        header("Content-type: text/sql");
        header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename='".$filename."'");

Answer (score 1):

In some case, you just can't force it.

It depends upon browser settings. for example in firefox -> preferences, there is an option to select:

- Save files to __
- Ask everytime.

So if the user has selected save file to_*_* option, this save-as window wont open, regardless of whatever programming you do in your PHP code.

If you want some example headers, you can have these in your php file, before outputting any content:

```
header("Content-type: text/csv");
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=$filename.csv");
```